# Rails and Oracle: execute sql statement and get all data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rather complex sql statement that is created on the fly. But the same problem exists for a simple query, so I use this one as an example.

I have a Feature model. I can call `Feature.count` --> 4

But if I try to get all Feature ids using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ID from features")` the result is a `OCI8::Cursor` object. I do not know how to get the data out of it.

If I try `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ID from features").fetch` I get `[1]`. With `xyz.fetch_hash` I get `{"ID" => 1}`.

I would like to have all IDs.
I just switched from PostgreSQL to Oracle.

Using PostgreSQL, I got all data using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ID from features").to_a`, but `to_a` does not exist using the `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` gem (`*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'to_a' for #<OCI8::Cursor:0x00000007028aa8>`).

I am using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4. The connection to the Oracle database is working, except my manually created statement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution.

Old: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ID from features")`

New: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT ID from features").to_a`

Maybe someone have the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you use the pluck method for this? ie: Feature.pluck(:id)

Comment: Because this was an example. I had the same problem with a complex sql statement. But I thought it is easier to explain and to understand if I use Feature as an example.

Comment: @Bjoernsen absolutely right. I'm working on a project where the sql queries are quite complex and ActiveRecord make more problems than it solves! Thanks a lot!